# XPath for elements with content inside?

Tags: c#, html, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack` and I have the following situation:

```
<table class='table-main odds '>   
   <tbody>
      <tr>..</tr>
      <tr>..</tr>
      <tr>..</tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

as you can see only three `tr` have content inside, so I want that in the final result should be available only the first three `tr`. Actually my code return all the `tr`:

```
 HtmlNode oddsTable = doc.DocumentNode
          .SelectSingleNode("//table[starts-with(@class, 'table-main')]");
 HtmlNodeCollection rows = oddsTable.SelectNodes("tbody//tr");
```

how can I achieve that using `xpath`?

Thanks for any help and explaination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by *content*:

- **Any content**: `//tr[node()]`
- **Element content**: `//tr[*]`
- **Text content**: `//tr[text()]`
- **Non-whitespace content**: `//tr[normalize-space()]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really interesting, have a good day :)